# Ajax request form

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Here are the links to my [web page](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~ckovuri/lab/lab7.html) and [source code](http://view-source:http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~ckovuri/lab/lab7.html). If you notice, I have a "Form". Once the user submits the application, the server gives him a reply through the file "submit.php". You can verify this online.

I'm trying to use that server reply by using AJAX request method to retrieve it, so i can post the same reply under right under the form once the user clicks on the button. I'm a newbie to web development, and I'm not sure what is wrong with my AJAX code. Any help would be appreciated. My submit.php code is below. For the whole directory [click here](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~ckovuri/lab/)

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$bday = $_POST['bday'];

echo "Reply from the server:";
echo "<br>";
echo "Thanks for your interest in our product!";
echo "<br>";
echo "We have filed the following Info:";
echo "<br>";
echo "Name: ";
echo "$name";
echo "<br>";
echo "E-mail: ";
echo "$email";
echo "<br>";
echo "Birthday: ";
echo "$bday";
?>
```

askServer is called upon submit button onclick event

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
function askServer() {

  req.open("GET", "submit.php", true);
  req.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
  req.send();

  document.getElementById("Sreply").innerHTML = "The request has been sent.";
}


function handleServerResponse() {
  if ((req.readyState == 4) && (req.status == 200))
 {
    var Sreply = 
req.responseText;
    document.getElementById("Sreply").innerHTML = "The answer is: " + Sreply;
  }
}
```

The below form is for the respondent @gaurav

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$bday = $_POST['bday'];

echo "Reply from the server:";
echo "<br>";
echo "Thanks for your interest in our product!";
echo "<br>";
echo "We have filed the following Info:";
echo "<br>";
echo "Name: ";
echo "$name";
echo "<br>";
echo "E-mail: ";
echo "$email";
echo "<br>";
echo "Birthday: ";
echo "$bday";
?>
```

Comment: Where did u try the ajax code?

Comment: You ask what is wrong with your AJAX code but didn't post any AJAX code.

Comment: @ kuya I guess you didnt read my description well. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you javascript code:-

```
  function askServer() {

     var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "submit.php";
var params = "name=samplename&email=test@example.com&bday=12-01-1993";
http.open("GET", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("Sreply").innerHTML = "The answer is: " + http.responseText;
    }
}
http.send(params);

    }
```

In you php code:-

change `$_POST` to  `$_GET`

once you get the right response change the example params according to the user input.

complete working html code:-

```
 <form id="appForm" action="" method="post">
     <label for="Name">Name </label> <br>
     <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Han Solo" required> <br>
     <label for="e-mail"> Email</label> <br>
     <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="example@uiowa.edu" required> <br> 
     <label for ="Birthdate">Birth Date</label><br>
     <input name="bday" id="datepicker" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">        
     </fieldset><br>
     <input class="btn-style" type="submit" value="Submit Application" onclick="askServer();return false;">
     </form>
         <p id="Sreply"></p>
         <script>
          function askServer() {

     var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "submit.php";
var params = "?name=samplename&email=test@example.com&bday=12-01-1993";
var url = url+params;
http.open("GET", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("Sreply").innerHTML = "The answer is: " + http.responseText;
    }
}
http.send(params);

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I intially used $_GET but from some reason im getting an error, hence i changed it post later. And even now im still getting the same error. 
Notice: Undefined index: name in /mnt/nfs/netapp1/homepage/ckovuri/lab/submit.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: email in /mnt/nfs/netapp1/homepage/ckovuri/lab/submit.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: bday in /mnt/nfs/netapp1/homepage/ckovuri/lab/submit.php on line 4

Comment: @ceeks just change you $_POST to $_GET in server side and it will work fine.

Comment: var params = "?name="+$('#name').val()+"&email="+$('#email').val()+"&bday="+$('#datepicker').val();

Comment: sorry about the long discussion, but with the new params, there is no reply/response back at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93329/discussion-between-ceeks-and-gaurav-srivastava).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make your ajax call on submit button onclick event, you need to stop the default form  submit event.

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
```

and your submit.php needs POST values, so make a POST request.

and you also need to pass the variable with that ajax request.

[a nice tutorial on ajax post requests](https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery)